# FileNotFoundException: Could not find file. Path given appears to correct maybe needs permissions?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hi im building an app for android via unity and I am trying to access a file on my computer for testing purposes.

> ```
> var stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\LIA\Documents\wat.txt", FileMode.Open);
>         bool ifexists = File.Exists(@"C:\Users\LIA\Documents\wat.txt");
> ```

Once i run the code avoce i get an " FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/C:\Users\LIA\Documents\wat.txt" " error on the logcat.

I am running the build on an external android device connected to the pc via USB, do I need to add permissions anywhere on unity so the android device can access these files ? Or is the error related to some other factor? I have tried running unity as admin but same error applied.

Appeciate any help, thx.

Error message:
[image]

File Location:
[image]

Full code:

```
        var stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\LIA\Documents\wat.txt", FileMode.Open);
     //   bool ifexists = File.Exists(@"C:\Users\LIA\Documents\wat.txt");
     
     //       Debug.Log("1: " + stream.ToString() + ifexists);

        //Firestore Reference
        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        storageReference = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://houdini-ac884.appspot.com");

        //Uploading to firestore
        StorageReference uploadRef = storageReference.Child("uploads/newFile.meta"); // Name of file
        Debug.Log("Beginning Upload;;");
        uploadRef.PutFileAsync(stream.ToString()).ContinueWithOnMainThread((task) => {
            if(task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled){
                Debug.Log("Upload Failed with following error:");
                Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            }else{
                Debug.Log("File Uploaded with success");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Looking at the log, it's placing a "/" at the start of your file path which may be your problem. What I don't understand is if the app is running on Android, why are you trying to access Windows file system?  The Android device won't know anything about that.  Could you clarify? In addition, consider the order of your operations.  You should check the file exists first, before trying to open it.

Comment: I wanted to test wether i could upload a random file to my firebase storage to check if the connection was set properly and getting a random file on the android device isnt as simple. as for the "/" its not written in the code itself it just shows in the logcat im not sure why, I have since updated the question with the rest of the code.

Comment: @EcocativeAxis to me it seems like it's trying to load from Android local storage, where the / at the start is the relative path to the app location on Android.  I doubt very much you're going to be able to access the Windows file storage from the external device like you're attempting.  I would go out on a limb and say it's impossible (via usb).  You'd need some sort of network connection from device to pc to be able to get it at the very least

Comment: Even if there is a windows compatible usb drive android uses unix notation. There is no c or d drives. There are just mount points.